# document.getElementById() not getting a value

Tags: javascript

I have a div:

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

and in my js:

```
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "foo";
```

this works correctly however...

I try to store it...

```
var rslt = document.getElementById('results');
```

so I can use it more easily. However "rslt" is undefined and in firebug when I mouse over "results" inside the getElementById brackets it doesn't display any info. Like it's a string??

I'm sure this is probably very simple and I just can't see it...

When I call rslt it gives "null" now. But if I remove the "var reslt = " the rest of it "document.getElementById('results')" works perfectly and returns the div.

Comment: Its working perfectly

Comment: It is working dude… :) http://jsbin.com/defen/1/edit?html,js,output. The reason is because the DOM hasn't load yet your div ;-) see my answer.

Comment: No need to use window.onload()... just add the script after div not before

Comment: I declared the variable as global and now I have assigned it in $('document').ready I hope that is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if it is **undefined** that means one simple thing - the object hasn't made it to the DOM tree yet.

Make that call after you're sure the div has been written to the document, e.g. after load event.

Comment: This is not the answer.. you could comment

Comment: I must have made a syntax error before because I tried setting it after the page had loaded but it still didn't work. I tried again now and it has worked. :/ Guess I got too stressed at why it wasn't working I didn't see the simple problems. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers mate. Glad you've figure it out :)

Answer (score 3):

```
window.onload = function(){
    var rslt = document.getElementById('results');
    rslt.innerHTML = "This is working.";
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It is Working Perfectly..Look at the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26HhR/)

```
<div id="results"></div>
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "foo";
```